What is the “Reinforcement Axiom” for a social choice function?
I recently came across this Computational Social Choice lecture note from Stanford, where an axiom for social choice functions called “Reinforcement” is introduced as a desirable axiom. I am trying to make sense of this axiom, but I can’t.
Let $N$ be a finite voter set, let $A$ be a finite alternative set, let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all linear order profiles on $A$, and let $f:\mathcal{P}\to 2^A$ be a social choice function.
A social choice function $f$ is reinforcing if for any two profiles $P,P’\in\mathcal{P}$ such that $f(P)\cap f(P’)\neq\emptyset$, $f(P+P’)\subseteq f(P)\cap f(P’)$.
I don’t understand the axiom because I can’t quite figure out the meaning of adding two preference profiles (i.e., $P+P’$).

The axiom is mentioned and discussed at https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/u.endriss/pubs/files/BrandtEtAlMAS2012.pdf It seems to refer to slightly different settings where the group of voters can vary.

Thank you for the comment and the very useful document you shared—it was not obvious to me at all that the document I found was dealing with populations of variable size.

In the formalism being used here, a profile $P$ is a vector, indexed by the set of all linear orders on the set $A$.  Each component of this vector is a non-negative integer, indicating the number of voters who report a certain preference order.  Thus, the vector sum $P+P'$ represents the profile obtained by merging two disjoint populations of voters, where one population is described by the profile $P$ and the other population is described by the profile $P'$.
The "reinforcing" property essentially says:  if the population described by profile $P$ selects some subset $C\subseteq A$, and the population described by profile $P'$ selects some subset $C'\subseteq A$, and $C\cap C'\neq \emptyset$, then the "merged" population (described by the profile $P+P'$) should select some subset of the (nonempty) intersection $C\cap C'$.

Thank you for your answer—it was not obvious to me at all that the document I found was dealing with populations of variable size.
